# Setting default overlay specification for itemize environment

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some question ...

(a) Part a of question 
\begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
  \item Step 1 of solution
  \item Step 2 of solution
\end{itemize}

(b) Part b of question
\begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
  \item Step 1 of solution
  \item Step 2 of solution
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Question

In Beamer, is there a way to make `[<+(1)->]` a default option for the `itemize` environment (and only this environment)? I would prefer not to use the `enumitem` package, for its compatibility issues with Beamer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `\renewcommand{\itemize}` and set the default overlay specification (after `\begin{document}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\olditemize\itemize
\begin{document}
% Update itemize to have a default overlay
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][<+(1)->]{\olditemize[#1]}

\begin{frame}
Some question ...

(a) Part a of question 
\begin{itemize}
  \item Step 1 of solution
  \item Step 2 of solution
\end{itemize}

(b) Part b of question
\begin{itemize}
  \item Step 1 of solution
  \item Step 2 of solution
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Werner! Wasn't aware of `\LetLtxMacro` before `:)` BTW, why does it have to be after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Related to the question in my previous comment, using `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][<+(1)->]{\olditemize[#1]}}` doesn't seem to work. If you prefer, I can ask a new question about this.

Comment: @KevinC: Ask a new question, since I can't seem to find a quick work-around.

Comment: A new question is asked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186411/where-to-put-renewcommand-in-beamer.

Answer (score 3):

You can put it into the preamble:

```
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
```

This way, all of your overlay will be overwritten.

Ref: [Applying \pause for each item in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314349/applying-pause-for-each-item-in-beamer)