# Where to put \renewcommand in Beamer

Tags: beamer, macros, hooks

This question is related to [Setting default overlay specification for itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186274/setting-default-overlay-specification-for-itemize-environment).

In the above-linked question, [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) provided a solution that uses `\LetLtxMacro` and `\renewcommand`. However, `\renewcommand` must be put *after* `\begin{document}`. Interestingly, using `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand...}` in the preamble won't work either.

Renewing the `\alert` command, in contrast, works regardless of where it's issued.

## Questions

- Why does `\renewcommand\itemize...` need to be put after `\begin{document}` while `\renewcommand\alert...` doesn't?
- Why does `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\itemize...}` not work, while it works for renewing `\alert`?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\olditemize\itemize

% \renewcommand{\itemize}[1][<+(1)->]{\olditemize[#1]} % doesn't work
% \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][<+(1)->]{\olditemize[#1]}} % doesn't work

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\alert[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}} % works
% \renewcommand\alert[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} % works

\begin{document}
% Update itemize to have a default overlay
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][<+(1)->]{\olditemize[#1]} % works

% \renewcommand\alert[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} % works

\begin{frame}
Some question ...

(a) Part a of question 
\begin{itemize}
  \item Step 1 of \alert{solution}
  \item Step 2 of solution
\end{itemize}

(b) Part b of question
\begin{itemize}
  \item Step 1 of solution
  \item Step 2 of solution
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\AtBeginDocument` is executed just before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Sigur: I think `\AtBeginDocument{<code>}` executes `<code>` immediately after `\begin{document}`. For example, `\AtBeginDocument{some text}` will print `some text` at the beginning of the document; whereas putting `some text` at the last line of the preamble will cause an error due to missing `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is the way `beamer` modifies definitions of standard environments such as `itemize`.  The file `beamerbasecompatibility.sty` includes:

```
  \AtBeginDocument{% fix frenchb.ldf's meddling with itemize and :
    \let\labelitemi\beamer@labelitemi
    \let\labelitemii\beamer@labelitemii
    \let\itemize\beamer@itemize
    \let\list\beamer@list
    \let\@trivlist\beamer@@trivlist%
    \catcode`<=12\catcode`>=12}
```

as part of its redefinition of `\begin{document}`.  In particular, this means that `beamer` delays redefining `\itemize` to the beginning of the body of the document.  Thus any changes you make before that will be overridden.

Actually `\AtBeginDocument` is defined as follows

```
\def\AtBeginDocument{\g@addto@macro\@begindocumenthook}
```

and `beamer`s version of `\begin{document}` contains the macro `\beamer@lastminutepatches` near the end (and `\beamer@firstminuteptaches` near the beginning).  So you can get your definition in to this late list of commands from the preamble as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\beamer@lastminutepatches{\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][<+(1)->]{\olditemize[#1]}}
\makeatother
```

Things work more straight forwardly for `\alert` as `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` simply provides the definition at the time that file is read.  So you can put your redefinitions in the preamble as below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\olditemize\itemize

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\beamer@lastminutepatches{\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][<+(1)->]{\olditemize[#1]}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\alert[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} % works

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some question ...

(a) Part a of question 
\begin{itemize}
  \item Step 1 of \alert{solution}
  \item Step 2 of solution
\end{itemize}

(b) Part b of question
\begin{itemize}
  \item Step 1 of solution
  \item Step 2 of solution
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```