# csquotes and beamer: citation for blockquote flush right on separate line

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, csquotes

With  `csquotes`, the (optional) citation of a long `\blockquote` is by default placed immediately after the quotation itself. If you want to have the citation on the next line, and flush right, you can do

```
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{#1#2\par\hfill#4#3}
```

which works fine in the standard classes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes,lipsum}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{#1#2\par\hfill#4#3}
\begin{document}
\blockquote[Some Bloke][]{\lipsum*[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in `beamer` this does not work, the redefinition of `\mkblockquote` has no effect as far as I can see. Is there some way of making this work in a `beamer` frame as well?

MWE, note position of *(Some Bloke)* compared to the example with `article` above:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{csquotes,lipsum}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{#1#2\par\hfill#4#3}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\blockquote[Some Bloke][]{\lipsum*[2]}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(By the way, I do of course know that I don't need `csquotes` to make a quote like that, so an answer that says something like *"ditch the `\blockquote` and use `\lipsum*[2]\par\hfill(Some Bloke)`"* isn't all that interesting.)

Comment: I thought you could do it with `\beamer@lastminutepatches` (cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186436/34551), but that won't work…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due to a bug in `csquotes` which is fixed in [version 5.2a](https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/releases/tag/v5.2a) (release date 2017-02-03). Analysis and work-around for pre-5.2a release follows.

---

An application of `\tracingall` or placing a 'marker' inside `\mkblockquote` will reveal that it is never executed in the `beamer` case. The reason is that `csquotes` checks the TeX is in an 'appropriate' mode for creating display material as part of `\blockquote`. If that test fails, the quote is set as a textual quote.

The test used by `csquotes` is the primitive `\ifinner`, which is true inside the primitive constructs `\hbox` and (crucially) at the start of a paragraph in a `\vbox` or `\vtop`. (TeX is in restricted horizontal mode and restricted vertical mode, respectively.) Frames are created in `beamer` as vertical boxes, so the first material placed in the frame has exactly the latter condition. This means that `csquotes` sees the context as 'not appropriate' for display and goes down the textual route.

We can exit vertical mode into unrestricted horizontal mode using `\leavevmode` (or a range of other horizontal mode commands), which will fix the issue.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{csquotes,lipsum}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{#1#2\par\hfill#4#3}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\leavevmode
\blockquote[Some Bloke][]{\lipsum*[2]}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the `article` case, TeX is in *unrestricted* vertical mode (the main vertical list) when `\blockquote` is encountered so `\ifinner` is false and the block quote route is chosen.

---

The defective code was

```
\long\def\csq@bquote#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \csq@ifnested
    {\csq@err@nbquote}
    {\csq@getpunct{%
       \ifbool{inner}
         {\csq@bquote@ii}
     {\ifbool{csdisplay}
        {\csq@bquote@i}
        {\iftoggle{csq@parbox}\csq@bquote@ii\csq@bquote@i}}%
     {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
```

where the faulty line is `\ifbool{inner}`. As noted, this will be true in both horizontal mode and vertical mode boxes. Replacing with

```
\ifboolexpr{ bool {inner} and bool {hmode} }
```

fixes this as it is now only true inside an `\hbox`. The fix makes the documented behaviour inside `\parbox` and similar active as they set the `csq@parbox`, whilst as `beamer` uses a 'raw' `\vbox` for frames it now works as-for the main vertical list.

One could use `etoolbox` to patch the defective code whilst waiting for an update:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\csq@bquote}{\ifbool{inner}}{\ifboolexpr{ bool {inner} and bool {hmode} }}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```