# Applying \pause for each item in beamer?

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause

In order to make items appear sequentially in beamer mode, I would typically use:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item No.1 \pause
\item No.2 \pause
\item No.3 \pause
\end{itemize
```

So I have to type '\pause' three times.

Is there instead something like:

```
\pauseall \begin{itemize}
\item No.1 
\item No.2 
\item No.3 
\end{itemize
```

... which applies '\pause' to each item?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes. Consider the option `[<+->]` for `itemize`, `enumerate`, and `description`:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item first
\item second
\item third
\end{itemize}
```

See [Section 12](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) of the Beamer manual for details.

Comment: All true but remember not to overdo this!

Comment: @JosephWright, why not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @bonifaz Not a technical issue: more a question of creating good presentations. In general, using 'reveal point by point' should be quite limited in presentations, and indeed text on slides should be carefully considered as the slides should be there to support what you say.

Comment: @JosephWright indeed, but it depends on the content an presentation style. Revealing point-by-point prevents the audience from reading the whole slide at once. It can be a good thing, if the presenter wants to be “in charge”, and if crucial points need to be revealed incrementally, but can get frustrating if the audience prefers to read at its own pace

Answer (score 8):

put into the preamble:

```
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
```